# Cloning hardidsk of 128GB into a 500 GB is not using the rest free space

Tags: partitioning, lvm, resize

I have just cloned my hard disk of 128 GB to a big one of 500GB . I have use commands dd to do it. The partition of ubuntu was done with lvm in the first installation. So when I plug in the new hard disk , the free space is not included in the /home , so I have to resize the partition. [image]

I have been booting from an usb live and after checking the partition I have got it to be like this now:

[image]

But still my /home has not more capacity

[image]

And this is how it looks

[image]

PS: RESOLVED!
I have been using commands lvextend -L and resize2fs for that partition to be resized. It works. Still is weird that is not a easy way with an easy interface like gparted.

Comment: Yes. That is correct. A clone will make a clone, and the new image wouldn't be much of a clone if it were different from the original ...

Comment: So it is there a way of using all that space?

Comment: With a new drive, it would have been a good time to convert from the 1980's era MBR(msdos) partitioning to the newer gpt partitioning. You then could have done a new install & resync'd data. Or LVM has its own tools. GPT Advantages (older 2010 but still valid)  see post#2 by srs5694:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1457901 & 
https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Partitioning#Choosing_between_GPT_and_MBR